# Stretch svg background without keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I want to use an svg image as background-image,
I want to show the entire image (no crop) and stretch the image to 100% height and width of the container div **without** keeping the original aspect ratio.

I was hoping this will work:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

But it doesn't, height is 100% but the width isn't, it's keeping the original aspect ratio.

If I use a png image instead of svg it does work.

Is there a way to do it with svg?

Comment: Depends on what the `preserveAspectRatio` is set to in the actual SVG code I'm guessing. Do you have the SVG code?

Comment: Thank you!! I knew nothing about svg but now I know a little more, adding preserveAspectRatio="none" was the solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solution:

Open the svg file in a text editor and add this attribute:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

Answer (score -3):

```
.sample {
   height:500px;
   width:500px;
   background-image: url('sample.svg');
   background-size:cover;
   background-position:center center;
}


<div class="sample"></div>
```

Just try it. I hope this will help you

Comment: What if screen size is less than 500px or more than 500px?

Comment: Thanks but background-size:cover crops the image for keeping the original aspect ratio

Comment: @niyasc this is just a sample

Answer (score -3):

Use

```
height:100% ;width:100%; background-size:contain;
```

to keep background aspect ratio.

Comment: Would probably work with png, but I just tried it with svg and it doesn't stretch to 100% width because it's keeping the aspect ratio, there's probably a trick that's specific to svg.

Comment: Actually.. I just saw you wrote "to keep aspect ratio", I'm trying to NOT keep aspect ratio..